# Problema com email com imagem incorporada

Tags: php, envio-de-email

Estou tentando enviar e-mail com imagem incorporada no texto através do *boundary*.

No Gmail tudo lindo, como sempre, mas no Outlook não chega o texto em  HTML e a imagem chega como anexo.

```
<?
@date_default_timezone_set('America/Bahia');
$imagem_nome="imagens/logomarca.png";
$arquivo=fopen($imagem_nome,'r');
$contents = fread($arquivo, filesize($imagem_nome));
$encoded_attach = chunk_split(base64_encode($contents));
fclose($arquivo);
$limitador = "_=======". date('YmdHms'). time() . "=======_";
$limitador2 = "_=======". date('sYmdHms'). time() . "=======_";

$mailheaders = "From: xxx@yyyyy.com.br\r\n";
$mailheaders .= "MIME-version: 1.0\r\n";
$mailheaders .= "Content-type: multipart/related; boundary=\"$limitador\"\r\n";
$cid = date('YmdHms').'.'.time();

$texto="
<html>
<body>
<img src=\"cid:$cid\">
<font size=6><br />blablabla </font>
</body>
</html>
";

$msg_body = "--$limitador\r\n";
$msg_body .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"$limitador2\"\r\n";
$msg_body .= "--$limitador2\r\n";
$msg_body .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$msg_body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\r\n";
$msg_body .= "$texto";
$msg_body .= "--$limitador2--\r\n";



$msg_body .= "--$limitador\r\n";
$msg_body .= "Content-type: image/png; name=\"$imagem_nome\"\r\n";
$msg_body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$msg_body .= "Content-Disposition: inline; filaname=\"$imagem_nome\"\r\n";
$msg_body .= "Content-ID: <$cid>\r\n";
$msg_body .= "\n$encoded_attach\r\n";
$msg_body .= "--$limitador--\r\n";

if(mail("zzzzzzz@hotmail.com","TEste",$msg_body, $mailheaders)){
    echo"Mensagem enviada";
}

?>
```

O que posso fazer para resolver o problema?

Comment: Então, quando se trata de e-mail, sempre é indicado a utilizar tabelas, para ficar padronizado em todos os clientes de e-mail, pois como mesmo você disse ou outlook é o que mais dá dor de cabeça. Segue um documento para você ver algumas dicas [Padrão de criação de E-mail Marketing](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1j8dHbsF4wd74hZ3OgkSV0JsR8A4eGI-Bc--uA6bH_Es)

Comment: Eu estou fazendo algo parecido usando o PHP Perl Mail, apenas adiciono a imagem com Attach e tudo dá certo.

Answer (score 2):

O seu script tem vários erros. Vou mencionar alguns.

- Você tem uma parte definida como quoted-printable, então precisa codificar essa parte como quoted-printable usando a função [quoted_printable_encode](http://www.php.net/quoted_printable_encode)
- Faltam quebras de linha separando cabeçalhos e corpo das partes da mensagem
- O cabeçalho content-disposition tem um erro, onde diz filaname deveria ser filename
- Você também tem inconsistências no caractere das quebras de linha, uma hora é \n outra hora é \r\n. O certo deveria ser \n se está usando Linux ou \r\n se está usando Windows.

Eu descobri esse erro salvando a mensagem gerada dos cabeçalhos e corpo para um arquivo e depois passei para a minha classe [MIME parser](http://www.phpclasses.org/mimeparser). Essa classe processa mensagens e tolera erros com os da mensagem gerada pelo seu script. Habilitando os avisos, aparecem esses erros todos que mencionei.

Mas viu, o certo para não ficar estudando os padrões do e-mail recomendo que use alguma classe pronta e madura para compor e enviar email. Eu desenvolvi a class [MIME email message](http://www.phpclasses.org/mimemessage) para esse efeito, mas existem outras se preferir. O que importa é não reinventar a roda e se beneficiar do conhecimento compartilhado por outros em componentes maduros.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido cara, passei a usar o phpmailer, mais simples e não preciso me preocupar com cabeçalho. Vlws!! Galera

```
    require_once('mail.php');
$database = new Database();


$pnt_not = $database->query("SELECT * FROM notificacao WHERE notificacao_id = '1'")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
// NOTIFICAÇÃO
$notificacao_id = $pnt_not['notificacao_id'];
$not_imagem = $pnt_not['not_imagem'];
$not_texto =  $pnt_not['not_texto'];
$not_assunto = $pnt_not['not_assunto'];


$sql_pes = "SELECT pessoa.pessoa_id, pessoa.pes_nome, pessoa.pes_email, pessoa.pes_senha FROM pessoa 
            WHERE pessoa.pes_newsletter =  'S' 
            AND pessoa.pessoa_id NOT IN(SELECT notificacao_log.pessoa_id FROM notificacao_log WHERE notificacao_id = '".$pnt_not['notificacao_id']."')";
$arr_pnt_pes = $database->query($sql_pes)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($arr_pnt_pes as $pnt_per){  
    // PESSOA
    $pes_email = $pnt_per['pes_email'];
    $pessoa_id = $pnt_per['pessoa_id'];
    $pes_nome = $pnt_per['pes_nome'];
    $pes_senha = $pnt_per['pes_senha'];

    // MENSAGEM
    $mensagem = "<center><img alt=\"Dengue na Web\" src=\"cid:img_incorporate_1\"></center><p></p>";
    $assunto = str_replace('#data#',  date('d/m/Y'),  $not_assunto);
    $mensagem .= str_replace('#pessoa#',  $pes_nome, $not_texto);
    $mensagem = str_replace('#link#',  '<a href="http://xxxxx/">Dengue na Web</a>', $mensagem);

    //MAIL
    $mail->AddAddress($pes_email);
    $mail->Subject = $assunto;
    $mail->AddEmbeddedImage('imagens/logomarca.png', "img_incorporate_1");

    if(!empty($not_imagem) && file_exists($not_imagem)){
        $mail->AddEmbeddedImage($not_imagem, "img_incorporate_2");
        $mensagem .= "<p></p><center><img alt=\"Dengue na Web\" src=\"cid:img_incorporate_2\"></center>";
    }

    $mail->Body = utf8_decode($mensagem);

    if($mail->Send()){
        $database->query("INSERT INTO notificacao_log (pessoa_id, notificacao_id, log_data) VALUES ('$pessoa_id', '$notificacao_id', NOW())");
        $mail->ClearAllRecipients();
        $mail->ClearAttachments();
    }
}
```